# data i had posted below and i want to upload it to django model and want to convert the image_link to our local host link

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
{
    "news_by": "Entertainment ",
    "news_title": "'Sarileru Neekevvaru' teaser: Mahesh Babu is visually pleasing, but Prakash Raj takes the cake again",
    "news_description": "Mahesh Babu is a pleasure to the eye, much like always, and 'Sarileru Neekevvaru' teaser is high on style quotient too, but Prakash Raj will win you over once again",
    "image_link":"https://cdn.dnaindia.com/sites/default/files/styles/third/public/2019/11/22/882305-sarileru-neekevvaru-teaser.jpg"
  }
```

Comment: use JSONField() to save the data..

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in a json object and use string replace to change the url domain.

```
import json
j = """{ "news_by": "Entertainment ", "news_title": "'Sarileru Neekevvaru' teaser: Mahesh Babu is visually pleasing, but Prakash Raj takes the cake again", "news_description": "Mahesh Babu is a pleasure to the eye, much like always, and 'Sarileru Neekevvaru' teaser is high on style quotient too, but Prakash Raj will win you over once again", "image_link":"https://cdn.dnaindia.com/sites/default/files/styles/third/public/2019/11/22/882305-sarileru-neekevvaru-teaser.jpg" }"""

l = json.loads(j)
l['image_link'] = l['image_link'].replace('https://cdn.dnaindia.com', 'http://localhost')
print(json.dumps(l))
```